# What does $d^n\textbf{x}$ mean in this context?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, notation, multiple-integral

I found the following on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Multiple_integration).

> Integration over more general domains is possible. The integral of a function $f$, with respect to volume, over an $n$-dimensional region $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is denoted by symbols such as: $${\displaystyle \int _{D}f(\mathbf {x} )d^{n}\mathbf {x} \ =\int _{D}f\,dV.}$$

What does $d^n\textbf{x}$ mean in this context? Is it a abbreviation for $dx_1dx_2 \dots dx_n$?

Comment: That is how I read it.

Comment: You linked to the wrong section of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: If you find an integral on Wikipedia and open the image in a new tab, you might notice that the title of the tab is the LaTeX code for that integral. No need to print-screen.

Comment: I would read $d^n \mathbf{x}$ as integration with respect to the vector $\mathbf{x}$, whereas $dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_n$ suggests that we are dealing with iterated integrals. Under suitable conditions, this will be equivalent as a consequence of Fubinis Theorem.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I'd actually say just the opposite. When you have a product of differentials grouped together as a single entity, that is usually to suggest a multidimensional volume element. For iterated integrals though, we really should include brackets to make the order of operations clear, e.g., we should write $\int_{0}^{1}\left[\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right]\mathrm{d}x$. It's because of the Fubini theorem that we are able to omit these brackets in practice with little confusion.